# Nominating a non-citizen to be the recipient of assets

Tags: canada, assets

I am a Canadian citizen with several savings accounts and fixed deposits in Canadian banks. However, my family members are not citizens of Canada.

If something were to happen to cause me to not be available to use and maintain these assets, how would I go about authorizing a non Canadian to be the nominee for my assets?

More specifically, I would like my parents to have the rights to my savings accounts and fixed deposits but they do not having a Canadian SIN and are not residents of Canada. If it helps, the banks in question are TD Canada Trust and Presidents Choice Financial.

Comment: This is more a legal question than one of personal finance. If you are concerned about someone needing to operate your accounts in case of serious illness, you should consider creating a suitable power-of-attorney and appoint someone to operate the accounts. If you ae concerned about death, you should consider making a Will leaving your assets to beneficiaries. In either case, you need to consult an attorney (don't use forms available on-line), and especially if it would be necessary for beneficiaries/attorneys to _travel_ to Canada from abroad to operate the accounts/close them down, etc.

Comment: Note that the problem has nothing to do with your family members not being citizens. It's more about them not having Canadian SINs and not being resident. I am not a Canadian citizen and had no problems inheriting, but then I live in Canada and pay taxes here.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. Being considered resident for tax purposes was good enough for me at the initial stages but that doesn't hold for them

Comment: Consider using a pro as Dilip says.  There is no problem for just saving accounts and such.  You might have a problem with investment accounts as the broker can't take instructions from a non-resident.